# Architecture quest - what is the efficient way to track an opportunity amount being used and reallocate the unused balance

Tags: apex, architecture, business-logic, design, businessprocess

To all the sf experts out here, trying yo get your inputs for a use case that i’m trying to incorporate. Use case: We have a currency field called “Amount Owed” on opportunity which holds an $ value. It is calculated by user based on any unused amount for that opportunity. Example if an opp Amount = $1000 and only $800 was spend in reality, then the Amount Owed = $200 which will then be applied to future opportunities under that account. (Note: This Amount Owed can be applied to a single oppty or to multiple opportunities.)

Questionn: That said, business needs a way to track where, when and to which Opportunities was this $200 got applied to as a credit. Also they want the ability to run reports showing this.

My Ideaa: Thinking on to create a custom object named “AmountHeld” which would hold the actual amount owed on the oppty record and then have a child record associated to “Amount Held” called “AmountDistributed” which would then hold the credited amount value along with oppty name to which credit was applied to.

Please let me know if i’m thinking in the right direction in regards to business logic implementation & also reporting perspective? if not pls share your inputs. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I often try to split sales activity (opportunities/deals) from payment operations.  I'd just have the closed won opportunity create a new Contract record for $1000.  Then I'd record account payments against the contract and roll them up to the contract.  This would give you reporting on open contracts with remaining balances, etc.

FWIW, this is bit of a judgement call.